# insert 2 images in sql database from vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table tenant in my sql 2005 database. It has the following members, where tdoc and tpic are of datatype `image`:

- tid
- tname
- tadd
- tph
- tdoc
- tpic

I want to insert 2 images from 2 picture boxes to `tdoc` and `tpic` using VB.NET.

I managed to write the following code for my record save button. Please help me with further code.

```vb
Private Sub bsave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bsave.Click
    If ((tname.Text = "") Or (tadd.Text = "") Or (tphn.Text = "")) Then
        MsgBox("Details are Incomplete", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else
        conn.Open()
        Dim s As String = "Insert into rent values('" & tid & "','" & tname.Text & "','" & tadd.Text & "','" & tphn.Text & "',@doc,@photo)"


        MessageBox.Show("Name & Image has been saved", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        conn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

I would like to use a `MemoryStream`, please just guide me with it.

Comment: a) use SQL Parameters b) validate your data c) if the ID is an IDENTITY, dont insert it, let the DB manage it d) where is your SqlCommand object?  Fix those things then it will be time to wonder about working with images.  Start with all the  questions listed under **Related** on the right ===>

Answer (score 0):

I have used this logic in my C# project hope it helps you.

```
using System.IO;

private void **BrowseFile_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

    dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.pnbg)|*.png|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
    dlg.Title = " Select Bike Picture";

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        String picLoc = dlg.FileName.ToString();
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picLoc;
        textBox9.Text = picLoc;
    }
}

private void **SaveButton_Click**(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs1 =newFileStream(textBox9.Text,System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

    byte[] image = new byte[fs1.Length];

    fs1.Read(image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs1.Length));
    fs1.Close();

    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmdupdt = new SqlCommand("Insert into TableName values(@pic )",con);
    SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter("@pic", SqlDbType.VarBinary, image.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, image);

    cmdupdt.Parameters.Add(prm);
    cmdupdt.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
}
```